# Node-Red to InfluxDB Cloud HTTPError: 405

Tags: influxdb, node-red

I have a problem setting up my connection between my raspberry pi and influxDB cloud.
The raspberry pi serves as MQTT broker (using mosquitto). I subscribed to the topic (temperature, humidity (..)) and now want to store this data in my InfluxDB Cloud.
I wanted to use node-red for this.
I successfully get the MQTT messages looking like that with the MQTT in node:

```
{"topic":"esp/dht/temperature","payload":22.1,"qos":0,"retain":false,"_msgid":"e7133e911452b1e4"}
```

Now I just want to store the plain object in my influxDB without changing the object (for now). Therefore I put in a influxDB out node.

I configured it like that:

- URL: https://westeurope-1.azure.cloud2.influxdata.com/orgs/9999999999999
- Token: My All Access token generated in influxDB Cloud UI
- Organization: uibk
- Bucket: test
- measurement: temperature

This throws an HTTPError 405:

```
HttpError: 405 Method Not Allowed : <html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.22.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the problem here?

edit:

screenshots of influxdb out node

[image: influxdb out properties]

[image: influxdb out properties]

Comment: We probably need to know which InfluxDB node you are using, becaues those options don't appear to match node-red-contrib-influxdb

Comment: I use the node-red-contrib-influxdb

I provide an screenshot.

Comment: Looks like the node needs updating/fixing https://github.com/mblackstock/node-red-contrib-influxdb/issues/132

Comment: Any alternative approaches I can try?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. I would start by checking for any other influxdb nodes on https://flows.nodered.org